# issue while adding react-dropzone to react-16.13.1 project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-dropzone

I want to add https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-dropzone to a React project written in TypeScript. And I am using the Yarn package manager.
So I hit the command *yarn add @types/react-dropzone*, which actually installs another deprecated package https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/react-dropzone.
Currently in my package.json ->

```
"@types/react-dropzone": "^5.1.0"
```

I found something is wrong when I saw it working in Firefox but not in Chrome.
How can I install the actual package(*https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-dropzone*)?

Answer (score 0):

As [npm site says](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/react-dropzone), you dont need @types/react-dropzone because the original package now contains everything needed.

[image]